# Plain TeX bold math in section titles

Tags: tex-core

I apologize if this question is very similar to others, but the other solutions have not worked for me. I am using plain TeX, and trying to make the math in my section titles bold. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of just stating that other solutions didn't work for you, it would be better to also show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Set up the math fonts for the bold version.

```
\font\tenib=cmmib10
\font\sevenib=cmmib7
\font\fiveib=cmmib5
\font\tensyb=cmbsy10
\font\sevensyb=cmbsy7
\font\fivesyb=cmbsy5
\font\tenexb=cmexb10

\def\boldmath{%
  \textfont0=\tenbf \scriptfont0=\sevenbf \scriptscriptfont0=\fivebf
  \textfont1=\tenib \scriptfont1=\sevenib \scriptscriptfont1=\fiveib
  \textfont2=\tensyb \scriptfont2=\sevensyb \scriptscriptfont2=\fivesyb
  \textfont3=\tenexb \scriptfont3=\tenexb \scriptscriptfont3=\tenexb
}

\catcode`@=11
\outer\def\beginsection#1\par{\vskip\z@ plus.3\vsize\penalty-250
  \vskip\z@ plus-.3\vsize\bigskip\vskip\parskip
  \message{#1}\leftline{\bf\boldmath#1}\nobreak\smallskip\noindent}
\catcode`@=12

Some text and a formula $a+\sum_i a_i\otimes c$

\beginsection Some text and a formula $a+\sum_i a_i\otimes c$

Some text and a formula $a+\sum_i a_i\otimes c$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Argh: `\outer`!!!

Comment: @JosephWright Would you dispute Knuth's authority? `;-)`

Comment: Hans introduced `\frozen` in LuaMetaTeX.  That's going to be the new `\outer`.

Comment: Knuth did provide `\pmb` on page 386 of the TeXbook.  It's not part of TeX or even listed in the index (except under boldface).

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's only for real emergencies.